# apache - mod_rewrite + mod_proxy working in staging, not working in production ( [P] option ignored )

Tags: proxy, apache-http-server, logging, mod-rewrite

I have set up a redirect in my Apache virtual host serving several subdomains - call them a.example.com and b.example.com - serving a ruby on rails app.

On my virtualhost config file I have this rule:

```
rewriteEngine on
rewriteRule proxy/(.+)$ http://news.example.com/$1 [P]
```

The idea is that I can do `http://a.example.com/proxy/news/a` and get the contents of `http://news.example.com/news/a`, but within the same subdomain, so ajax doesn't think my ajax requests are cross-domain - [more info on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412843/apache-can-i-make-a-proxy-server-with-just-apache/9429240#9429240).

The problem is that while it works just fine in my staging environment, it does not in production!

Both servers are Ubuntu server 10.04 . Apache came from the standard ubuntu repos, using `apt-get install`.

I have made a diff of the whole /etc/apache2/ dir and the only difference is the server name.

If I change the last option to [L], I get a redirect, so this makes me think that mod_rewrite is working. It just doesn't talk with mod_proxy.

By looking at the logs (`/var/log/apache2` and the rails log), it seems like the rewrite rule in production is simply being ignored - the logs are exactly the same as if it wasn't there.

How can I debug this? Can I force Apache to give me more information about why this particular rule isn't enforced when I access `/proxy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realized that this was the wrong place to ask this kind of question.

I'm moving this question to serverfault, and will mark this answer as "correct" as soon as I'm allowed. If you were going to answer this question, please do it here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/364471/apache-mod-rewrite-mod-proxy-working-in-staging-not-working-in-production